# How to determine this angle in terms of other variables?

Tags: geometry

I have a little question.

I am trying to determine the angle in the following image, in terms of other variables (to solve another problem down the line)

Initially, I have this:

[image: easy]

This consist of two circles touching at two points, they are equal side and symmetric on both sides. The angle is the tangent to the sides that are touching

I derived the angle to be 1/2R

Now on to the next problem, it is quite similar- but it's three circles

[image: hard]

Again, it is symmetrical on all sides, L1=L2=L3 and R1=R2=R3 and all the angles are the same as well. The top angle isn't drawn properly, it should be tangent to the two sides joining in (just like the first picture)

Any thought on how to get the angle in terms of L, R or both ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to re-phrase your question a bit first. [1] According to your diagram, the two circles are not “touching”, but intersecting instead. [2] What is “they are equal side and …”? [3] If they are symmetric on both sides, then why in your diagram has L(1) and L(2)? [4] What is tangent to the “sides”?

Comment: @Mick Hi, sorry english is not my first language.
[1] Yes they are intersecting, at a symmetrical point. Sorry for confusion[2] The arcs are equal in length, it is the same size circle, intersecting at symmetric point (left side is a mirror of the right side). [3]I have L(1) and L(2) because that is what the initial question asked, but after some calculations, I found out that they are equal, disregard their differences. [4] If you made two imaginary line that are tangent to the circles at the intersection point, it would create an angle. That is the angle I am seeking

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution. I am just trying to help.

Does the following figure reflect what the question is talking about?[image]